# pretty print nested fields

Tags: python, nested

I have a list of string like this :

```
['array<struct<creationdate:bigint,enddate:bigint,error:string,executionuuid:string,requestcontext:string,responsecontext:string,ruleclass:string,startdate:bigint,state:string>>']
```

And I would like to have the following result:

```
ARRAY<STRUCT<
  creationdate BIGINT,
  enddate BIGINT,
  error STRING,
  ...
  ...
 >
>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make this into a python?

Comment: Is it Impala syntax?

Comment: Hive syntax, @OlvinRoght

Comment: Seems like there's no neat solution, you can try to apply [opensource sql parser](https://eng.uber.com/queryparser/) from Uber.